# Error report - ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create this below table but I'mm getting the error I don't understand why, could someone explain?

```
CREATE TABLE STUD (
    RNO NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT PK_RNO_STUD PRIMAY KEY,
    SNAME VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT NN_SNAME_STUD NOT NULL,
    COURSE VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT NN_COURSE_STUD NOT NULL,
    FEE NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT NN_FEE_STUD NOT NULL,
    MOBILE NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT UK_MOBIE_STUD UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT CK_RNO_STUD CHECK(RNO BETWEEN 1 AND 60),
    CONSTRAINT CK_COURSE_STUD CHECK(COURSE IN('ORACLE','SQL SERVER','UNIX')),
    CONSTRAINT CK_FEE_STUD CHECK(FEE BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000)
);
```

> Error report - ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here
>   02253. 00000 -  "constraint specification not allowed here"
>   *Cause:    Constraint specification is not allowed here in the statement.
>   *Action:   Remove the constraint specification from the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE STUD (
    RNO NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT PK_RNO_STUD PRIMARY KEY,
    SNAME VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT NN_SNAME_STUD NOT NULL,
    COURSE VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT NN_COURSE_STUD NOT NULL,
    FEE NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT NN_FEE_STUD NOT NULL,
    MOBILE NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT UK_MOBIE_STUD UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT CK_RNO_STUD CHECK(RNO BETWEEN 1 AND 60),
    CONSTRAINT CK_COURSE_STUD CHECK(COURSE IN('ORACLE','SQL SERVER','UNIX')),
    CONSTRAINT CK_FEE_STUD CHECK(FEE BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000)
);
```